# I can't use ContractResolver in net core 3 startap

Tags: .net-core-3.0

I've tried:

```
options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

but net core 3 startup don't support this assign

Comment: What are those classes? Don't force people to google those names just to find out what you're asking about

Comment: If the question is `where is JSON.NET ?`, it was announced months ago that .NET Core will have its own JSON serializer. That was also announced during the launch yesterday, in the live sessions, the blog posts, the docs etc. Either modify your code to use the new serializer or add JSON.NET back. You may only need to add the correct package

Comment: ASP.NET Core uses System.Text.Json now which uses camel-case by default. You don't need that line at all. What are you trying to do? What does your configuration code look like? Perhaps all you need to do is remove the JSON.NET configuration code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net core uses System.Text.Json now but you can still use Newtonsoft if you want to.
In your startup.cs file add the following in ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new JsonCustomContractResolver();
            });
```

That should do it